# How LibXmlParsing can parse in chunks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, libxml2

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    xmlParseChunk(context, (const char *)[data bytes], [data length], 0);
}
```

my Question is as follows

=> didReceiveData: method receives data in parts

Some what like this

- first data----------|      <masterData>Main</ma
- second data-----|     ster><masterData>Main2
- third data --------| </masterData>

=> How xmlParseChunk() method can parse all these chunks successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's [XMLPerformance sample app](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/XMLPerformance/index.html) illustrates a complete implementation of libxml2 integrated with NSURLConnection and chunk parsing. I found it very helpful.

Comment: Yes. I have that sample code. & I have placed the same method, from the sample code. But I am not clear about it's working.

There is a method # xmlParseChunk() # in it. it has defination but no body.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. xmlParseChunk is implemented in the libxml2 library. With every chunk of XML data you pass to it, it can continue parsing a bit further. Presumably, if xmlParseChunk encounters an imcomplete XML tag such as in your example, it just stops parsing until you pass it more data. I guess it uses the xmlParserCtx pointer to maintain its state.

Comment: Oke ! that's great. that's what I didn't understood.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have your delegate contain an [NSMutableData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) member and invoke [appendData:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000173-BGBCAEJD) when you get new data. Then parse it when your delegate gets the `connectionDidFinishLoading` message.

Comment: This would be functionally no different than parsing once the entire document is loaded in memory, which defeats the purpose of parsing in chunks.